# S20, S20+, S20 ultra device Problem, Cant' fetch data from API

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Good morning, stackoverflowers.

I have built one hybrid mobile apps using React-Native.
But I have trouble to signup/login to this app on S20, S20+.
All functionality is working fine on the Android9 device and Android10 device, and S10 as well.
But on S20, S20+, no response, when I tap login and signup button.
On S20, S20+ device, I can access the backend API URL.
But in the app, can't access and can't fetch data from API.

How can I fix this problem?

I'd love to hear from experienced members, thanks

Answer (score 2):

S20, S20+ are newly version, they were released on 6th March.
I had also similar case, seems like RN doesn't support full functionality on S20 and 20+. I guess that need to wait releasing of RN new version